# Tibble data to excel

Tags: r, excel, tibble

I want to transfer the data in the following tibble to excel. Is there a way to do it?

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
id_cat <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
sex <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1)
dis_cat <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
measurement <- c(10, 13, NA,13, 12, 11, 14, NA)
myData <- data.frame(id, id_cat, sex, dis_cat, measurement)
myData

library(dplyr) ; 
myData %>% group_by(id_cat, sex) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(measurement, na.rm = TRUE), SD = sd(measurement, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                percentile = quantile(measurement, c(0.05), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Writing out a tibble is the same as writing out any other data.frame in R. See the duplicate question for some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
#Data
df1 <- myData %>% group_by(id_cat, sex) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(measurement, na.rm = TRUE), SD = sd(measurement, na.rm = TRUE),
                                               percentile = quantile(measurement, c(0.05), na.rm = TRUE))
#Export
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df1),file='MyFile.xlsx','Sheet1',row.names = F)
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(myData),file='MyFile.xlsx','Sheet2',row.names = F,append = T)
```

Comment: @Duck- write.xlsx function is from the xlsx package? I am trying to install the xlsx package and load it using the library() function but I am getting the following error                   
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:

Comment: @PriyamK Try also install `rJava`

Comment: @PriyamK - try the `writexl` package, which does not require Java.

Comment: @PriyamK Also you can try `write.xlsx()` from `openxlsx`